# Using XPATH to select the row *after* a row containing certain text

Tags: xpath

I can't work out if this is possible or not, I've got a basic table but that table has a varying number of rows and data within it.

Assuming the table is just one column wide and a random number of rows long to select a row containing the text "COW" I can do something very simple like do: -

```
table/tbody/tr[contains(td[1],"COW")]/td[1]
```

But lets say that this table contains two types of data in it, a list of animals and, underneath each animal, a list of attributes, all in the same column, looking something like this: -

```
COW
Horns = 2
Hooves = 4
Tail = 1
CHICKEN
Horns = 0
Hooves = 0
Tail = 1
```

Is there a way using XPATH to first identify the row that contains the text COW and then select the row directly after this to return the text "Horns = 2"?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want something like this:

```
table/tbody/tr[contains(td[1],"COW")]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]
```

This will select the first `td` in the row immediately following the row which contains the `td` which contains `COW`.

Comment: Hole in one, excellent cheers!  I wasnt aware of the "following sibling" option in XPATH, very handy! :)